# Why is the changing-link-color scheme so subtle for beta sites?

Tags: discussion, design, beta-sites

If you view this [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/49889/14213) and hover your cursor over the text, you can see each link clearly because it changes color dramatically, (assuming your device has a hover method and the color contrast is suitable for your vision).

But in beta SE sites the color shift is much more subtle, perhaps tiny even.

When a two-or-more word phrase is linked, this makes it much more difficult to tell if each word is its own link, or if there is one link for the whole phrase.

There are other ways to tell, browsers may offer other feedback about the link under the hover, but a larger color shift would make the task simpler, especially if the colors were chosen to offer contrast for the largest possible population.

Would an alternate choice for these colors as default for the beta SE sites be more user-friendly?

> [image: good mouseover highlighting contrast]

versus

> [image: bad mouseover highlighting contrast]

**note:** for those with GIFs disabled in your browser, the above images are **both** GIFs, but you hardly notice the 2nd one because the two colors are nearly identical.

---

**update:**  I've added this issue/item in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313059/303080) and it was well received. The new design for beta sites has been released; see for example [Responsive design released for all Beta & Undesigned sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315662/303080).

The new design adds an underline, makes the color even fainter, and the contrast between highlighted and unlighted even more difficult to notice in my opinion.

This is a GIF:

> [image: EVEN WORSE mouseover highlighting contrast]

Comment: Thats because its a known fact that beta styles suck