# Missing whitespace in beta site statistics box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, statistics, beta-sites

At least for successful beta sites, the new design seems to result in a lack of whitespace between the numbers and what the numbers represent.

Because a picture is worth a thousand words, even though this particular example comes straight off the presses at [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/):

[image: Writing SE Site Stats]

Comment: This has already been reported as the top answer to [Responsive design released for all Beta & Undesigned sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/responsive-design-released-for-all-beta-undesigned-sites)