# Alignment issues on Meta SE search results page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, search

The search field is too wide, causing the <kbd>Search</kbd> button to overlap with the site icons in the Hot Network Questions list.

The tag description box seems to extend too far to the left, *or* the text above it is positioned too far to the right.

This might possibly be related to my choice to hide the left sidebar across the network; I haven't actually tried this with the sidebar visible.

[See for yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bbug%5d%20statistics):

[image: Meta SE Search Results screenshot]

The above is with Firefox ESR 60.2.1 on 64-bit Debian GNU/Linux. The black part to the right of the URL bar isn't actually black; I just blacked out my browser extensions' toolbar buttons.

<sub>Yes, that's a real search; I was trying to see if [Missing whitespace in beta site statistics box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315860/157730) had already been reported.</sub>

Comment: No repro on Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Reproducible in Firefox Nightly 64.0a1 with a width from 817px to 1047px (though there’s no actual overlapping beyond 1022px due to the margin) or at a zoom level of 200% and, for whatever reason, 90% and 50%.

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been solved: the search field and corresponding button are no longer shown on the search results page anymore; you have to use the one in the top bar instead.

[image]

Comment: You know there is a close reason for this kind of thing, right? ;)