# Can we suggest design improvements in sites?

Tags: support, design

Can we suggest design improvements for sites? Like on Travel.SE <sup><sup>*[Example Question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38177/how-do-you-know-if-americans-genuinely-literally-mean-what-they-say)*</sup></sup>, I can suggest the arrow design. If the moderators like that design, they can use this design.

Comment: Voting arrows are no longer customizable *aime*. You might be interested in reading this (in chronological order) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/responsive-design-released-for-all-beta-undesigned-sites

Comment: When SU had a design that we were unhappy with - we actually went through our meta, and a post here. Mods rarely use back channels, and usually for *urgent* not *important* things. And no, we don't have a special, direct say on site designs.

Answer (score 8):

Stack Exchange is actually moving away from deep customisation for sites, and towards more consistent branding. Even in the past, while each site would collect ideas for SE design folks, it still was SE design that was implemented.

Mods have nothing to do with design.

In summary - no, not really :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but [not for mobile, which is identical](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4491) for all sites. I've done it on [Photo.SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5721/37074).

The Q&A for Travel.SE is "[Travel SE Design Round 2](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061)" - if your suggestion is limited, "*could* include colors of sections of the design or text", try in the "[Travel's updated site theme is live!](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4824)" Q&A instead. The "images" might be changeable, the [layout won't be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes), but I managed both by politely asking early when the window was open.

You're a bit late to the party but exceptional (and highly upvoted) answers might convince the designers and community manager to consider your input over what they went with.

Comment: I think the point of responsive design is to not have a separate mobile design.

Comment: You'll need to bring that up in that thread as an answer, we can't help you here.