# Bring back site-specific fonts to the new design

Tags: feature-request, design, fonts

For example, [English Language & Usage's updated site theme is ready for testing!](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11693/239338) is perceived badly, where one of the reasons were the old design looking old-fashioned, including the Serif font.

Other site-compelling fonts include Open Sans on Graphics Design and a few other sites, and Roboto on Android Enthusiasts. The site-specific fonts are a special highlight of the sites. Normalizing them would to some extent normalize the user experience on those sites.

Can we bring back site-specific `font-family` for individual sites **globally** (not just for titles and bodies)?

Comment: Related: 1. [Static, unchanging font size, leading, and measure incompatible with dynamics of responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316797/static-unchanging-font-size-leading-and-measure-incompatible-with-dynamics-of) 2. [Why do some parts of the standard theme use different fonts than the rest of the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315762/why-do-some-parts-of-the-standard-theme-use-different-fonts-than-the-rest-of-the)

Comment: 3. [What does constructive criticism of a design change look like?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like)

Comment: IMMA GO TO IPS AND ASK "How can users convince a large company to refrain from rolling out stupid changes"

Comment: Ha, ha... yes maybe we do need to improve out interpersonal skills but if you're serious, I don't think that's going to help. SE is already taking knocks and a lot of criticisms lately, the fire has been lit, there's enough wood burning for the time being.

Comment: Related: [Fonts and the new Q&A theming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311033), [Can we at least select our own fonts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307865)