# What happened to the 2018 monthly product team updates?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, meta, announcements

There was no update in the [2018 monthly product team updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305560/271215) page for the past two months (September and October). Last month I got a reply from Adam Lear that September update will be included in October but the October update didn't surface as well.

With so much changes going on in Stack Exchange including the [beta site redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315662/271215), [changes to HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316934/271215), etc... I would like to see a monthly update.  When can we expect a monthly update?

Comment: In 6-8 weeks, probably

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most simple answer ever. I suck. I will do a three in one update to cover the missing months just as soon as I finish this next episode of *The Great British Baking Show*.

[image: "Good, Good. Let the Procrastination flow through you." - Darth Sidious]

Really, just one more episode and I'll get the update done.

P.S. Sorry for the lack up updates. I really will get them up early next week.

Comment: The downvoter lacks a sense of humour I guess

Comment: @Stijn Well. What ya gonna do. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hey! No spoilers please!

Comment: "Early next week"?  Is that anything like "six to eight weeks"?

Comment: @Stijn I downvoted after Joe left SE, leaving scorched earth behind. This answer is a sad joke.

Comment: @ShadowTheCurlyBracedWizard yeah I can see how this answer didn't age well 

Comment: @ShadowTheCurlyBracedWizard ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯