# Meta-participation by mobile users?

Tags: support, mobile-web, per-site-meta

How are any users of small screen devices expected to discover that a Meta site exists? And do they tend to do so, in fact?

Do users of small screen devices see any kind of notification when a meta-topic is "featured"?

Apart from "featured", and posting in chat, is there anything else a moderator can or should do to notify the community (including mobile users) that there's currently a featured Meta-topic -- or in fact that there is any activity on Meta, on a site where there's often little?

Can a moderator see what device (e.g. mobile or otherwise) any given user is using, i.e. to understand what they are or are not seeing? For example Discourse displays "Recently Used Devices" in the Preferences of my user profile there, I imagine that may be visible to moderators. Is there any means at all on SE (e.g. if one knows how to read a User Agent header)? Is that information something which CMs might ever conceivably give to a site moderator, if they were to ask?

Comment: See [Responsive design released for all Beta & Undesigned sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315662/289905).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not under the impression that meta is *particularly* discoverable (and it's one of those things users stumble upon over time)- there are no obvious signs of per-site metas except under either the SE button on the responsive site top bar or the hamburger menu on the mobile view.

On my own site, we haven't featured anything in a bit, but the "featured on meta" block on the side bar vanishes when it's on a small/narrow screen on responsive view. In theory we can (ab)use chat events for site-wide announcements, but that's rarely done. I'm not entirely sure how this works on phones - I think the last time I did it was about five years ago.

> Do users of small screen devices see any kind of notification when a meta-topic is "featured"?

No

> Can a moderator see what device (e.g. mobile or otherwise) any given user is using, i.e. to understand what they are or are not seeing?

No

> Is that information something which CMs might ever conceivably give to a site moderator, if they were to ask?

I doubt so - and in most cases, you might just ask the user directly. Aggregate device/OS information might be interesting though.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested that on a 4'' Android phone (hard to get smaller screen nowadays). I opened a random Stack Overflow question in Chrome and at first sight, there was nothing about meta.

However, after I checked a tick at [Desktop site option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11702453/839601) things changed and I was able to see community bulletin with featured meta questions (had to scroll down closer to page bottom for that).

[image: featured on meta on 4'' device]

Looks like users of small screen devices are expected to pick desktop site option if they are willing to see meta announcements.